# Submiting only one form with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have several forms in my html view (they displayed by php foreach).
Form example:

```
<form method="POST" class="like-form-js">
 <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?= $post['id'] ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value=<?= CoreController::findIndentityId(); ?>">
 <i class="far fa-thumbs-up color-grey c-pointer submit-like"></i>
</form>
```

I have many such forms in my view. My js:

```
$('.submit-like').click( function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'some-url',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('.like-form-js').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
    });
```

I need to submit only one form on which i clicked, but this forms have similar class and they are all submiting. How to solve this?

Comment: you are not submitting any forms with this code. You are calling several ajax pages, that is different. Try to explain better what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify which form to be submitted 
Try this,

```
$('.submit-like').click(function(){
     $(this).parent().submit()
})

$('like-form-js').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
            url: 'some-url',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
})
```